# Understand the BSOD mini dump errors

Tags: windows-10, bsod

On **Sept 10th** I experienced very bad failures (BSOD) which cycled up to 10 times and finally I gave up and did a system reset (clean install with a delete on all software but keeps all the files safe).

After that the same day, I tried again after the clean install and still there were 2 BSOD and I gave up entirely.

Since then I haven't touched my PC and decided to give it one more try. This time everything seems OK so far. I have analyzed the mini dump files to trace back what caused the problem.

These are my findings so far:

these are the [images](https://imgur.com/a/YAsSX)

```
 - default_bucket ID: win8_driver_fault
 - process_name: Microsoft edge
 - module name: nt
 - image_name: ntkrnlmp.exe
```

Here is another one from another dump file:

```
 - DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
 - BUGCHECK_STR: 0x3B
 - PROCESS_NAME: GoogleUpdate.exe
 - MODULE_NAME: nt
 - DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 58ccba4c
 - IMAGE_VERSION: 10.0.15063.0
 - STACK_COMMAND: .cxr 0xffffc901bb714610 ; kb
 - IMAGE_NAME: memory_corruption
```

All the dump files upto this date is located [here](http://www.filedropper.com/sept10dump)

**UPDATE Sunday 09-17**: BSOD again today ! The mini-dump analysis doesn't make any sense to the previous two! This latest dump file is located [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byj8JxXAeyj_WmdqZFlOLXlHcHc/view)

```
FAULT_INSTR_CODE: 107d8366
SYMBOL_NAME: nt!CcUnmapVacbArray+fd
FOLLOWUP_NAME: MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: nt
IMAGE_NAME: ntkrnlmp.exe
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 59ae237e
IMAGE_VERSION: 10.0.15063.608
BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET: fd
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 0x1E_c0000005_nt!CcUnmapVacbArray
BUCKET_ID: 0x1E_c0000005_nt!CcUnmapVacbArray
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS: 0x1E_c0000005_nt!CcUnmapVacbArray
TARGET_TIME: 2017-09-15T21:30:20.000Z
OSBUILD: 15063
OSSERVICEPACK: 608
SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0
OS_REVISION: 0
SUITE_MASK: 784
PRODUCT_TYPE: 1
OSPLATFORM_TYPE: x64
OSNAME: Windows 10
OSEDITION: Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
OS_LOCALE:
USER_LCID: 0
OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP: 2017-09-05 00:09:34
BUILDDATESTAMP_STR: 160101.0800
BUILDLAB_STR: WinBuild
BUILDOSVER_STR: 10.0.15063.608
ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 1637
ANALYSIS_SOURCE: KM
FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING: km:0x1e_c0000005_nt!ccunmapvacbarray
FAILURE_ID_HASH: {9048ea71-0a8c-100a-cb69-5ff239abc3a2}
Followup: MachineOwner
```

Since then, I have been going back and forth with every installed software drivers, to make sure they are up to date. I however tried to do a firmware upgrade on my SSD containing the OS. But that gave me an IDE/AHCI incompatibility error which I believe is for another post here.

**EDIT:** [ALL DUMP FILES HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byj8JxXAeyj_SndCQnVDdzRnZkU)

*However I would greatly appreciate it if any one could give me further insights into this analysis. I would like to find the root cause of the problem and resolve it.*

Comment: run memtest86+ and test the RAM for errors.

Comment: Zip up the minidump files (all of them) and put them on a public file sharing service for others to look at.

Comment: @RickBrant : I have added the link to the post. Please check.

Comment: [update BIOS to 1.80](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/990FX%20Extreme9/#BIOS) (you use 1.50)  and test each of your CML8GX3M2B1600C11 modules on its own with memtest

Comment: @magicandre1981 will do today, first BIOS and then memtest86+ on RAM, when you say 'each on its own' do you mean I check each one physically ? That is use one RAM at a time on the MB ?

Comment: yes, remove all RAM modules except one and test each RAM on its own. if RAM is fine and updated BIOS doesn't fix it, test your HDD because CcUnmapVacbArray in dicates Cache Manager calls.

Comment: any update? have you updated the BIOS after testing all RAM?